# How can I estimate the readout time of an electronic camera shutter?

Tags: camera, optics

I would like your help in finding a way to estimate the readout time of a digital camera's rolling (electronic) shutter. Meaning, the time that it takes to scan a frame. I looked through the internet for ways to estimate it, but I couldn't find something.

I would highly appreciate any given help!

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know what a typical read-out time is, or do you want to measure the actual time of a camera by doing some experiment?

Comment: You are right I wasn't very clear. I want to measure the readout time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but one of the easiest is to have a LED chaser light system in a horizontal strip.

the chaser trip will have one LED on at a time at some time period of say, 1 ms.  You vies the strip and from that you can get your integration period (number of lights on) and frame rate (sift in start position from frame to frame.

You will have to play around with number of LED's, flashing time and other parameters.

Look [here](http://www.pv-imaging.com/LED_Chaser.html) for an industrial tool that does this.

Comment: Also notice that for most cameras, that time is not fixed, but adapts to light or is configurable, as measuring small voltage variations might be slower

Comment: @MarcusMuller your observation is correct, but I believe that if I measure the readout time in various light conditions I could come up with an average/representative value.

Comment: @placeholder thank you for your answer! It seems that this will work just fine. Do you happen to know the difficulty of creating a custom setup like the one you proposed?

Comment: @Nikos just make sure you've controlled the light environment so the exposure control  doesn't change the settings. It is fairly straight forward, search for LED chaser lights.